# How to calculate the eigenvalues of matrix with entries that are continuous functions of matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite, positive-matrices

I met the following problem during my research, could anyone please give me some help?

Let $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}, x\in \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric matrix in the form
\begin{align}
A(x) = \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  a_{1,1}(x) & a_{1, 2} (x)\\
  a_{2,1}(x) & a_{2, 2} (x)
  \end{array}\right], \quad \text{where} \quad a_{1, 2}(x) = a_{2, 1}(x),
\end{align}
and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is a positive semi-definite matrix in the form
\begin{align*}
D = \left[
  \begin{array}    {ccccc}
    2 & -1 &  & & -1\\
    -1 & 2 & -1 & & \\
       & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \\
       &   & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
    -1 & &  & -1 & 2
  \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}
Here, all unspecified entries of $D$ are zeros. $D$ has non-zero entries in the three main diagonal lines, and $D(1, N) = D(N, 1) = -1$.

Assume $A(x)$ is positive semi-definite for all $x \geq 0$, that is the eigenvalue functions of $A(x)$ satisfy $\lambda_i(x) \geq 0$. Is it true that $A(D)$ in the following form
\begin{align}
A(D) = \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
  a_{1,1}(D) & a_{1, 2} (D)\\
  a_{2,1}(D) & a_{2, 2} (D)
  \end{array}\right],
\end{align}
also has non-negative eigenvalues? How to prove it?

For example,
\begin{align}
A(x) = \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} x & x\\
 x& 2x
  \end{array}\right],\quad
A(D) = \left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{2} D & D\\
 D& 2D
  \end{array}\right].
\end{align}
$A(x)$ is positive definiteness for $x\geq 0$. Assume the eigenvlues of $A(x)$ are $\lambda_1(x)$ and $\lambda_2(x)$, and eigenvalues of $D$ are $\mu_k$, how to compute the eigenvalues of $A(D)$? Is it true that the eigenvalue are $A(D)$ are $\lambda_i(\mu_k), i = 1, 2$?

**EDIT1**:
For a general symmetric  $A(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{s\times s}$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, assume $\lambda_i(x)$ are eigenvalue functions of $A(x)$, and denote $\Lambda(x) = \mathrm{diag}([\lambda_1(x), \dots, \lambda_{s}(x)])$. Then it holds that
\begin{align*}
  A(x) & = P(x) \Lambda(x) P^{-1}(x), \\
  A(D) & = P(D) \Lambda(D) P^{-1}(D).
\end{align*}
Let $\Gamma = \mathrm{diag}([\gamma_1, \dots, \gamma_{N}])$ be the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, then we can write $D = F \Gamma F^{-1}$. Let $I_s$, and $I_N$ be the indentity matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{s \times s}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$, respectively. It holds that
\begin{align*}
  A(D) & = P(D) \Lambda(F \Gamma F^{-1}) P^{-1}(D) \\
  & = P(D) (I_s \otimes F) \Lambda(\Gamma) (I_s \otimes F^{-1}) P^{-1}(D)
\end{align*}
The eigenvalues of $A(D)$ are $\Lambda(\Gamma)$, that is $\lambda_i(\gamma_j), i = 1, \dots, s; j = 1, \dots, N$.

Are there mistakes in the above result?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The example function $A(x)$ you came up with is very simple, and so the question is very easy to answer in this case. If $A(x)$ is an arbitrary continuous function, however, things can become much more difficult

Comment: For your example, the eigenvalues are easy to find using the properties of the [Kronecker product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Comment: Thank you Ben! Yes, I can get the eigenvalues using Kronecker product for this simple example. For a general $A(x)$, assume its eigenvalues functions are $\lambda_i(x)$, and the eigenvalues of $D$ are $\mu_k$, will the eigenvalues of $A(D)$ be $\lambda_i(\mu_k)$?

Comment: What I was trying to get at with the first comment is that you should give us a more representative example function. The general answer is probably  “no”, but perhaps there is a class of functions that you’re interested in where something useful can be said

Comment: Dear Ben, I tried to calculate the eigenvalues of $A(D)$ in EDIT 1, could you help me check whether the calculation is correct? Thanks!

Comment: For $N\ge4$, your $D$ will not be positive semi-definite. If $x$ is the all-ones vector, then $x^tDx$ is the sum of the entries of $D$, which is negative for $N\ge4$. (I'm assuming all the unspecified entries of $D$ are meant to be minus ones; if they're meant to be zeros, well, never mind).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you Gerry! All unspecified entries of $D$ are zeros, I will modify the question.